# Increase security for remote desktop machine - use 2FA and/or limit to LAN connection only?

Tags: windows, security, remote-desktop, two-factor-authentication

I'm looking at setting up Windows remote desktop on a W10 Pro machine.

I'd like to increase the security on the connection and wonder if any of the following are possible:

- A password, different from the username used to login when physically using the machine. This way it could use a random generated string which I could input once from the dial out computer.
- 2 factor authentication.
- Limit all incoming connections to machines on the same LAN only.

There will be 3 computers that will connect to the host, mostly Macs.

Is any/all of these possible and are there some other things I should be looking at?

Comment: Are you simply connecting to this over a local LAN, or over the public Internet?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator it would be over local LAN, although there will be a dial in VPN in place

Comment: How many computers need remote access to this host? Do the connecting computer's IP addresses change?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator it will be 3 computers that will connect to the host, i could give the incoming 3 computers mac to IP bindings on the Router so they wouldnt change, are you thinking allong the line of IP based authentication as a additional piece of security ?

Comment: yes, or at minimum configuring the firewall on the Host to only allow connections to port 3389 from those 3 machines. IPSec would be much more robust, but more difficult to setup too.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator ill give that a try also, but what would stop the 'attacker' assigning them selves a bunch of static IPs in the network range and trying to connect using them ? (obviously they would still need to have the correct password)

Comment: IPSec can use certificates that authenticate the computers. Even if the attacker connects from the correct IP, without the certificate the connection can't be completed.

Comment: How much time and money do you want to invest on this? If you do a lot to secure the login and connections between the host and computers, you should also look at the attack face for the connecting computers, and possibly a lot of other things. Security is all about balancing convenience, risk and resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article
[Securing Remote Desktop (RDP) for System Administrators](https://security.berkeley.edu/resources/best-practices-how-articles/system-application-security/securing-remote-desktop-rdp-system)
lists these tips:

- Use strong passwords
- Update your software
- Restrict access using firewalls
- Enable Network Level Authentication
  (enabled by default for Windows 10)
- Limit users who can log in using Remote Desktop
  (default is all Administrators)
- Set an account lockout policy
  (lock an account after a number of incorrect guesses)
- Change the listening port for Remote Desktop
  (default is TCP 3389)
- Do not use other products like VNC or PCAnywhere

For your question about two-factor authentication,
I don't believe this exists on Windows 10 Pro,
only on Windows Server.

The article
[The 5 Best Alternatives To Google Authenticator](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-best-alternatives-google-authenticator/)
lists six products which have a free plan (but also paid ones) :
Google Authenticator, Authy, Duo, HDE OTP, Authenticator Plus, Sound Login Authenticator.
I have never used such products, so do not know how useful these are for you.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc do you know if its possible to set a password or key as part of the initial remote desktop login, so we would not be limited to memorable secure password that users would use to log in, but rather could use a 60 character random string as a pre shared key to supplement the users password

Comment: Windows 10 has the new technology of [Virtual Smart Cards](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/virtual-smart-cards/virtual-smart-card-overview) which in effect provides two-factor authentication. See the [Get Started with Virtual Smart Cards: Walkthrough Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/virtual-smart-cards/virtual-smart-card-get-started). I have never used it so cannot answer questions.

Comment: Virtual Smart Cards requires TPM 1.2. Does all your computers have that @sam?

Comment: @PatrikN i doubt it, the client machines are macs mostly

Comment: Unfortunately that's the only free product I know of. Commercial products can be found by googling for two-factor authentication.

Comment: @sam, regarding password, see my answer (about SSH). And since it's Macs, NLA can't be used either.

Comment: I have added a link to an article exposing six 2FA products which might help, but it's up to you to check them out.

Comment: @harrymc reading through the bullet points above it strikes me that the "low hanging fruit" (eg. the simplest to implement and the ones with the widest reach) would be to "Use strong passwords" and "Set an account lockout policy" so if there was a 10 char unique password and a 3 try lock out 30 minute policy regardless if someone had access to the ports they wouldnt really ever have the time to brute force their way it. Would setting just those 2 items up be enough in your opinion ?

Comment: There can never be an answer to the question of "what is enough". It all depends on the attack vectors that you wish to protect against. These two measures are a good protection against brute-force attacks, but they wouldn't help for example against the user that puts his credentials on a sticker.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the current info, my recommendations are:

- By setting up a **SSH tunnel**, you get an extra layer of authentication, where you can use another *username/password* or *public key authentication* to login. You can *also* enable **obfuscation**, with a completely different **password**, like you wanted. That way you also make it harder for someone monitoring the traffic to even see that it's SSH - and to connect, they both need that password and whatever SSH login you set up. Add to that, that it's tunneling RDP traffic, which is also encrypted.

  On the **Windows** machine you can *install* [Bitvise SSH Server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) and on the **Macs**, you can *add obfuscation support* to the built-in OpenSSH with some [pathes by ZingLau](https://zinglau.com/projects/ObfuscatedOpenSSHPatches.html).
- 2FA *might* be possible, but it won't be easy or free. The *built-in smart card logon **requires** a Windows Active Directory domain*, but there are 3rd party solutions for stand-alone computers. [EIDAuthenticate](https://www.mysmartlogon.com/products/eidauthenticate.html)  support **RDP** and is available in a **free** open source version, but *only for **Home editions*** (yet, they *are thinking about a "home use program"*, so contacting them might speed up that thinking). But in your case it might not be enough, since it's only for Windows, and you connects from a Mac.
- Limiting incoming connections to LAN, can easily be done in **Windows Firewall**.
- General things like **strong passwords** and **updating** all computers shall be done of course. I also recommend having **separate user and administrator accounts**, and *only allow the (unprivileged) user accounts to log on via RDP*, so the administrator account has to log on locally.
- The next thing I would look at, would be the **security on the clients** that connects, because *if they are compromised*, all the other things you have set up *doesn't help much*. But I'm talking about general security principles, so I won't go into details with that.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is possible with WebADM from RCDevs which is even free up to 40 users.

1. A password, different from the username used to login when physically using the machine.

Yes, WebADM is using LDAP, ActiveDirectory... So you can use different username/password.

2. Two factor authentication.

Yes, you can use TOTP, HOTP with Hardware/Software Token, email and sms.

3. Limit all incoming connections to machines on the same LAN only.

Yes, you can define Client Policy.

4. There will be 3 computers that will connect to the host, mostly Macs.

Yes, you can install Credential Provider Plugin for Windows or OSX with offline authentification.