# Is there a way to set up 2FA for login to my Windows system?

Tags: windows, windows-10, two-factor-authentication, windows-authentication

I have Windows professional and am **not** on a domain.

I'd like this for RDP on my desktop and for login & RDP on my laptop.

In response to a comment below - I want 2FA logging into my laptop. So if the laptop is stolen, they don't need to just break my password.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - that's not for RDC [which, as far as I can tell, is not available for  non-server versions of Windows] https://superuser.com/questions/1294040/increase-security-for-remote-desktop-machine-use-2fa-and-or-limit-to-lan-conne & others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase security for remote desktop machine - use 2FA and/or limit to LAN connection only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1294040/increase-security-for-remote-desktop-machine-use-2fa-and-or-limit-to-lan-conne)

Comment: You can set up a free Duo account and it's fairly simple to integrate with Windows logins. You have the option of requiring it for RDP only or for RDP and in-person logins.